# How to create a spring boot app with ssl.enable=true and a non-secure "/health" end point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, embedded-jetty

Is it possible to configure spring boot application ( Jetty ) to have at least one non-secure (non https) endpoint for a load balancer to perform health checks but have all other requests be forced to be secure?

When setting the property:

`server.ssl.enabled=true`

requests for all ports (both regular port and management/actuator port) are forced to be https.

Secure requests URLS must have the server name in the URL match the certificate configured.  A load balancer or container manager like kubernetes would have to access each node in a pool of servers with some kind of host name to server mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I thought that the setting `management.ssl.enable=false` would do the trick but it doesn't appear to be the case.  What I wound up doing that worked for me was to add an ssl exclusion rule for just the `/health` endpoint.

Here is an abridged version of my `SecurityConfiguration` which is a `@Configuration` annotated class that extends/implements `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter/WebSecurityConfigurer`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure-path").hasAuthority("SOME_ROLE")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling();



    if (securityProperties.isRequireSsl()) {
        //allow health checks to be over http
        http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/health").requiresInsecure();
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

making use of the `requiresInsecure()` for the `/health` endpoint was the key.  Note, the order is important, generally in Spring Security more specific rules should come first.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot 2 property for disabling the management server TLS is:

```
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
```

Comment: However, if server.ssl.client-auth=NEED and server.ssl.enabled=true, the property management.server.ssl.enabled=false will not work and the endpoint will still require HTTPS, if the port is the same, i.e. no management.server.port=xxxx override